# Clash between facebook and actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, facebook, actionbarsherlock, xamarin.android, xamarin

I've encountered a strange problem with my monodroid project, it has been working fine for ages using ActionBarSherlock (obtained via NuGet). I recently added the Facebook SDK binding provided by xamarin and from then on I see this error and hundreds of errors like it when I try to compile my project:

```
javac error :  package com.actionbarsherlock.app does not exist
javac error :   extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
javac error :
```

At first I wondered if it was just a bad package, or some weird corruption so I manually bound the Facebook SDK and imported it to the solution and I'm still seeing the exact same error.

I have updated everything I can, android SDK, VS 2012, monodroid etc. As I'm still seeing the error I'm assuming it's something to do with the facebook SDK, but the really weird part is in a test project the package works fine, so long as ActionBarSherlock isn't imported as well.

Does anyone have any experience of this problem, and any possible workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved. It was a bug in the Xamarin framework which has now been resolved, [see here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15573).